# Apply filter to current image index in UIScrollView GPUImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage, gpuimage

Im currently deploying a ImageScroller by UIScrollView, and it contain a filter toolbar at the bottom as you can see on the image.

[image]

But im facing a problem is that when i press the button, the filters is only apply to the last image as example below:

**`Gif` Example** 
[image: Gif Example]

So please anyone can help me to solve this one, my expected output is the filter is applied to the current displaying image, not only the last one. Here i would attach my code for your reference and thank you so much.

```
@interface EditImageVC ()
@end

@implementation EditImageVC


UIImageView *img;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int x=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _scrollViewImageArray.count ; i++) {

        _picture = [_scrollViewImageArray objectAtIndex:i];
        img =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,20,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 
        self.imgScrollView.frame.size.height)];
        img.image =_picture;
        x=x+[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
        [_imgScrollView addSubview:img];
    }
    _imgScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _imgScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(x, 
    _imgScrollView.frame.size.height);
    _imgScrollView.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0, 0);
    img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}


-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
     self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}



 - (IBAction)filterAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    for (int i = 0; i < _scrollViewImageArray.count ; i++) {
        UIImage *picture = [_scrollViewImageArray objectAtIndex:i];
        GPUImageFilter *selectedFilter;
        switch (sender.tag) {
            case 0:
                selectedFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
                break;
            case 1:
                selectedFilter = [[GPUImageToonFilter alloc] init];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        UIImage *filteredImage = [selectedFilter imageByFilteringImage:picture];
        [img setImage:filteredImage];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter the last shown image and when filter image when scrollview scrolled `to another image`.

remember to add UIScrollViewDelegate

```
@interface EditImageVC : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>   {
}

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imageViewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int x=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _scrollViewImageArray.count ; i++) {

        _picture = [_scrollViewImageArray objectAtIndex:i];
        img =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,20,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,

        self.imgScrollView.frame.size.height)];
        img.image =_picture;
        [imageViewsArray addObject:img];
        x=x+[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
        [self.imgScrollView addSubview:img];
    }
    self.imgScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.imgScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(x,
                                          self.imgScrollView.frame.size.height);
    self.imgScrollView.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0, 0);
    img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    self.imgScrollView.delegate = self;
}

GPUImageFilter *selectedFilter = nil;

NSInteger currentShownIndex = 0;
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSInteger indexAfterScrolled = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;
    if(indexAfterScrolled==currentShownIndex) return;
    currentShownIndex = indexAfterScrolled;
    if(selectedFilter!=nil) {
        UIImage *filteredImage = [selectedFilter imageByFilteringImage:[_scrollViewImageArray objectAtIndex:currentShownIndex]];
        [[imageViewsArray objectAtIndex:currentShownIndex] setImage:filteredImage];
    }
}

- (IBAction)filterAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    switch (sender.tag) {
        case 0:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 1:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImageToonFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    UIImage *picture = [_scrollViewImageArray objectAtIndex:currentShownIndex];
    UIImage *filteredImage = [selectedFilter imageByFilteringImage:picture];
    [[imageViewsArray objectAtIndex:currentShownIndex] setImage:filteredImage];
}
```

**Updated**
If you want to filter current shown image, not need to apply UIScrollViewDelegate:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        imageViewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        int x=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _scrollViewImageArray.count ; i++) {

            _picture = [_scrollViewImageArray objectAtIndex:i];
            img =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,20,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,

            self.imgScrollView.frame.size.height)];
            img.image =_picture;
            [imageViewsArray addObject:img];
            x=x+[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
            [self.imgScrollView addSubview:img];
        }
        self.imgScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.imgScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(x,
                                              self.imgScrollView.frame.size.height);
        self.imgScrollView.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0, 0);
        img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        self.imgScrollView.delegate = self;
    }

    - (IBAction)filterAction:(UIButton *)sender {
        NSInteger objectAtIndex:currentShownIndex = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;
            GPUImageFilter *selectedFilter = nil;

        switch (sender.tag) {
            case 0:
                selectedFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
                break;
            case 1:
                selectedFilter = [[GPUImageToonFilter alloc] init];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        UIImage *picture = [_scrollViewImageArray objectAtIndex:currentShownIndex];
        UIImage *filteredImage = [selectedFilter imageByFilteringImage:picture];
        [[imageViewsArray objectAtIndex:currentShownIndex] setImage:filteredImage];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I tried both solutions but its not work. For the 2nd solution, it threw an exception in for (UIImageView *subview...in..) loop. The exception is : [UIScrollView countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]

Comment: I forgot to do onething in my sample. init `imageViewsArray` in `viewDidLoad`. did you try that? @DuyKhanhNguyen

Comment: Thank you, its true that we need to init the imageArray, and the first one is worked, but about the second one, can you check again the for loop?. Cuz I need to apply filter to the current image, not the whole all.I mean when I scroll to each image, it should apply the filter to that image

Comment: oh.. i know. You want to show images in paging scrollview and show the 'current shown image' with selected filter(or no filter selected). Is that right? Then the second solution would always not work. I delete the not suitable solution.

Comment: Yeah, actually the flow is same as any editing images application, the filter should be applied on only current image. And at this solution, it still apply to all the images :(

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen I've change solution for just filter current shown image

Comment: Can i have your skype or smth else?

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen skype:codus@codus.me We can use the text chat because my English speaking ability is not very good